# How to wire a 480 V AC to 380 V AC transformer?

Tags: transformer, ac, safety, three-phase

[image]

[image]

I have to install a reflow oven which needs 3-phase 380 V AC to power on.

There is a transformer (as the picture shows) that came with the oven. I assume that the black wire is the "hot" wire. I don't understand why on the input 480 V doesn't have the black wire. Do I have to splice/join the black input and output together?

[image]

Comment: What is the label on the rightmost output terminal? Is there a rating plate on the transformer and, if so, can you provide a photo?

Comment: @Transistor On the rightmost output terminal, the label says each terminal: yellow, blue, red is 380 v, and black is 0v (4P , 200A) I assume 4p means 4 phase.

Comment: Please link the product documentation for the transformer. No documentation means guesswork which leads to bad decisions and, given the voltages you are talking about, it might lead to property damage or personal injury. What are your qualifications Henry? What is your job?

Comment: Henry, please get professional help with this project. With the best will in the world, I'm sorry to say you sound as if you don't know what you are doing. As others have said, there are lethal amounts of voltage (400V) and current involved. From the photograph it looks like a delta-star transformer and if you don't know what that is, stop right now! DO NOT connect the input to the output or the black wire to any other terminal! The black wire is almost certainly not the only "hot" wire and is probably the centre tap of the star windings.

Comment: `I assume 4p means 4 phase` "Close": look at the left terminal block. I guess *Screw Terminal Block 3Pole* and right 4 pole, respectively. This should be a "ΔY" transformer: neutral on secondary, but not on primary side. Don't use input neutral (black?), or fasten somewhere suitably isolated. Be sure to connect protective earth appropriately. Maybe have someone qualified have a look at it before applying power - there may be pitfalls not to do with this transformer & terminal block.

Comment: `I assume that the black wire is "hot" wire` ... making assumptions in this case can lead to serious injury

Comment: @Andyaka There is no documentation for the transformer. Only the oven has installation document. I am not a electrician. I am a electrical technician. I have experiences with electrical but not AC 3phase or transformer. I just want to learn and do my best for my company , but my company will have a professional to inspect my work. That is my plan for now.

Comment: (There seems to be an issue with bottom left screws. With "power devices", I'm a bit uneasy with metal parts gone missing.)

Answer (score 5):

The transformer is probably wired like this:

[image]
https://electrical-engineering-portal.com/3-phase-transformer-connections#delta-wye

Delta-Wye transformers are common because three phase mains usually doesn't have a Neutral, and the load sometimes needs a Neutral.

The colors are not standardized, you must use the labels. This transformer seems to use the color code used by India. The phasing order won't matter for an oven, but if the oven has colors and is labelled ABC or 123, I would be consistent with the colors. A quick internet search indicates that RST = ABC.

[image]
https://www.electricaltechnology.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Electrical-Wiring-Color-Codes-NEC-IEC-Single-Phase-Three-Phase-AC.png

The oven will probably use one phase to Neutral for the controller electronics.

\$ V_{phase} = \frac{V_{line}}{\sqrt{3}} \$

\$ \frac{380V}{\sqrt{3}} = 220V\$

Everything must be properly grounded, an Electrician should know how to do this. This would be done with separate ground wires, not any of the wires shown in the diagram.

As for Theodore's comment, if the transformer secondary is considered a mains distribution, then yes the neutral should be grounded. I don't know if this applies, it may depend on the country and local code. The oven may even connect the Neutral to ground (you can measure this with an ohmmeter, power disconnected of course).

And I agree completely with the warnings in the comments. You have not given us confidence that you are qualified for this job. 480V with high current capability is extremely dangerous. This has enough power to melt/vaporize large gauge wires. You don't want a spray of molten metal in your face.

Comment: Enlarge the picture and you will see chinese.

Comment: Another reason ∆-Y is common is because the neutral can be bonded to ground so that the phases aren't floating with respect to earth.  In US codes (not sure about OPs location), this would be required for a "separately-derived system" like this.

Comment: Yes, I will ask my workplace to have a professional to inspect my work. Most colors of oven and transformer are match, except the oven shows green and the transformer show blue instead. I think that's not a problem.